# SQL User with sysadmin role can't login to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a domain user account that I use to run a particular ASP.NET web application it is NETOPS\websvr.  This domain account is setup in the SQL Server in question and is in the sysadmin role.  However, I randomly get errors stating that the login failed for he user.  Sometimes it is on this database and others it is on a different database on the same server.

I have been searching the web for the past several hours trying to find an answer for this and I am no closer to an answer than when I started so I thought I would ask here to see if anyone has any ideas.  Below is a output from my instance of Stackexchange.Exceptional

```
Exceptions Log: WebSync
Cannot open database "alsmi" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NETOPS\websvr'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "alsmi" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NETOPS\websvr'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(String connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(String connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText)
   at GetPatchLevel.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
ClientConnectionId:e33983c0-da22-4050-a894-55274b46f645

Full Trace:

ProcessRequest at offset 424 in file:line:column :0:0
System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute at offset 342 in file:line:column :0:0
ExecuteStep at offset 70 in file:line:column :0:0
ResumeSteps at offset 1085 in file:line:column :0:0
BeginProcessRequestNotification at offset 96 in file:line:column :0:0
ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate at offset 187 in file:line:column :0:0
ProcessRequestNotificationHelper at offset 727 in file:line:column :0:0
ProcessRequestNotification at offset 31 in file:line:column :0:0
MgdIndicateCompletion at offset 0 in file:line:column :0:0
ProcessRequestNotificationHelper at offset 1110 in file:line:column :0:0
ProcessRequestNotification at offset 31 in file:line:column :0:0


occurred 2 hours ago on web1 (delete)
Server Variables
CONTENT_LENGTH  0
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR    0.0.0.0
HTTP_X_SSL_CIPHER   AES128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=AES(128) Mac=SHA
LOCAL_ADDR  192.168.1.117
REMOTE_ADDR 192.168.1.216
REMOTE_HOST 192.168.1.216
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
URL /Services/GetPatchLevel.ashx
URL and Query   http://website.net/Services/GetPatchLevel.ashx?dbname=alsmi&username=0000&pwd=0000&clientid=0000

Custom
SQL-Server  sqlserver1
SQL-ErrorNumber 4060
SQL-LineNumber  65536

QueryString
clientid    0000
dbname  alsmi
pwd 0000
username    0000

RequestHeaders
Host    website.net
X-Forwarded-For 0.0.0.0
X-SSL-cipher    AES128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=AES(128) Mac=SHA
Exceptional 1.0.0.111
SQL Error Store
Server time is 1/30/2015 5:50:04 PM
```

Here is the code that generates the connection string for the database.

```
   public static string GetConnString(string DBName)
{
    string retval = "";
    WebSyncDatabase db = WebSyncDatabase.GetDatabase(DBName);
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    csb.DataSource = db.DBServer;
    csb.InitialCatalog = db.DBName;
    csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    csb.ConnectTimeout = 25;
    csb.MaxPoolSize = 150;
    retval = csb.ConnectionString;
    return retval;
}
```

Here is the data access code.  The SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar is from Microsoft Data Access Application Block for .NET code unmodified.  he below code literally works tens of millions of times per day for us with random exceptions.

```
 string connString = WebSyncUtils.GetConnString(dbName);
        switch (context.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper())
        {
            case "GET":
                int retval = 0;
                try
                {
                    retval = (int)SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connString, CommandType.Text, "SELECT PatchLevel FROM PatchStatus");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WebSyncUtils.LogMessage(string.Format("Get Next Patch Level for {0} {1} {2}", dbName, userName, pwd), ex);
                }
                context.Response.Write(retval);
                break;
            case "POST":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

more code sample for Methodman

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Execute a stored procedure via a SqlCommand (that returns a 1x1 resultset) against the database specified in 
    /// the connection string using the provided parameter values.  This method will query the database to discover the parameters for the 
    /// stored procedure (the first time each stored procedure is called), and assign the values based on parameter order.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method provides no access to output parameters or the stored procedure's return value parameter.
    /// 
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  int orderCount = (int)ExecuteScalar(connString, "GetOrderCount", 24, 36);
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="connectionString">A valid connection string for a SqlConnection</param>
    /// <param name="spName">The name of the stored procedure</param>
    /// <param name="parameterValues">An array of objects to be assigned as the input values of the stored procedure</param>
    /// <returns>An object containing the value in the 1x1 resultset generated by the command</returns>
    public static object ExecuteScalar(string connectionString, string spName, params object[] parameterValues)
    {
        if( connectionString == null || connectionString.Length == 0 ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "connectionString" );
        if( spName == null || spName.Length == 0 ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "spName" );

        // If we receive parameter values, we need to figure out where they go
        if ((parameterValues != null) && (parameterValues.Length > 0)) 
        {
            // Pull the parameters for this stored procedure from the parameter cache (or discover them & populate the cache)
            SqlParameter[] commandParameters = SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(connectionString, spName);

            // Assign the provided values to these parameters based on parameter order
            AssignParameterValues(commandParameters, parameterValues);

            // Call the overload that takes an array of SqlParameters
            return ExecuteScalar(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, commandParameters);
        }
        else 
        {
            // Otherwise we can just call the SP without params
            return ExecuteScalar(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a SqlCommand (that returns a 1x1 resultset and takes no parameters) against the provided SqlConnection. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  int orderCount = (int)ExecuteScalar(conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetOrderCount");
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="connection">A valid SqlConnection</param>
    /// <param name="commandType">The CommandType (stored procedure, text, etc.)</param>
    /// <param name="commandText">The stored procedure name or T-SQL command</param>
    /// <returns>An object containing the value in the 1x1 resultset generated by the command</returns>
    public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText)
    {
        // Pass through the call providing null for the set of SqlParameters
        return ExecuteScalar(connection, commandType, commandText, (SqlParameter[])null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a SqlCommand (that returns a 1x1 resultset) against the specified SqlConnection 
    /// using the provided parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  int orderCount = (int)ExecuteScalar(conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetOrderCount", new SqlParameter("@prodid", 24));
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="connection">A valid SqlConnection</param>
    /// <param name="commandType">The CommandType (stored procedure, text, etc.)</param>
    /// <param name="commandText">The stored procedure name or T-SQL command</param>
    /// <param name="commandParameters">An array of SqlParamters used to execute the command</param>
    /// <returns>An object containing the value in the 1x1 resultset generated by the command</returns>
    public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        if( connection == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "connection" );

        // Create a command and prepare it for execution
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        bool mustCloseConnection = false;
        PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, (SqlTransaction)null, commandType, commandText, commandParameters, out mustCloseConnection );

        // Execute the command & return the results
        object retval;

        try
        {
            retval = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            if (mustCloseConnection)
                connection.Close();
        }           

        return retval;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a stored procedure via a SqlCommand (that returns a 1x1 resultset) against the specified SqlConnection 
    /// using the provided parameter values.  This method will query the database to discover the parameters for the 
    /// stored procedure (the first time each stored procedure is called), and assign the values based on parameter order.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method provides no access to output parameters or the stored procedure's return value parameter.
    /// 
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  int orderCount = (int)ExecuteScalar(conn, "GetOrderCount", 24, 36);
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="connection">A valid SqlConnection</param>
    /// <param name="spName">The name of the stored procedure</param>
    /// <param name="parameterValues">An array of objects to be assigned as the input values of the stored procedure</param>
    /// <returns>An object containing the value in the 1x1 resultset generated by the command</returns>
    public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlConnection connection, string spName, params object[] parameterValues)
    {
        if( connection == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "connection" );
        if( spName == null || spName.Length == 0 ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "spName" );

        // If we receive parameter values, we need to figure out where they go
        if ((parameterValues != null) && (parameterValues.Length > 0)) 
        {
            // Pull the parameters for this stored procedure from the parameter cache (or discover them & populate the cache)
            SqlParameter[] commandParameters = SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(connection, spName);

            // Assign the provided values to these parameters based on parameter order
            AssignParameterValues(commandParameters, parameterValues);

            // Call the overload that takes an array of SqlParameters
            return ExecuteScalar(connection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, commandParameters);
        }
        else 
        {
            // Otherwise we can just call the SP without params
            return ExecuteScalar(connection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a SqlCommand (that returns a 1x1 resultset and takes no parameters) against the provided SqlTransaction. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  int orderCount = (int)ExecuteScalar(trans, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetOrderCount");
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="transaction">A valid SqlTransaction</param>
    /// <param name="commandType">The CommandType (stored procedure, text, etc.)</param>
    /// <param name="commandText">The stored procedure name or T-SQL command</param>
    /// <returns>An object containing the value in the 1x1 resultset generated by the command</returns>
    public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, string commandText)
    {
        // Pass through the call providing null for the set of SqlParameters
        return ExecuteScalar(transaction, commandType, commandText, (SqlParameter[])null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a SqlCommand (that returns a 1x1 resultset) against the specified SqlTransaction
    /// using the provided parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  int orderCount = (int)ExecuteScalar(trans, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetOrderCount", new SqlParameter("@prodid", 24));
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="transaction">A valid SqlTransaction</param>
    /// <param name="commandType">The CommandType (stored procedure, text, etc.)</param>
    /// <param name="commandText">The stored procedure name or T-SQL command</param>
    /// <param name="commandParameters">An array of SqlParamters used to execute the command</param>
    /// <returns>An object containing the value in the 1x1 resultset generated by the command</returns>
    public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        if( transaction == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "transaction" );
        if( transaction != null && transaction.Connection == null ) throw new ArgumentException( "The transaction was rollbacked or commited, please provide an open transaction.", "transaction" );

        // Create a command and prepare it for execution
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        bool mustCloseConnection = false;
        PrepareCommand(cmd, transaction.Connection, transaction, commandType, commandText, commandParameters, out mustCloseConnection );

        // Execute the command & return the results
        object retval = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        // Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        return retval;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a stored procedure via a SqlCommand (that returns a 1x1 resultset) against the specified
    /// SqlTransaction using the provided parameter values.  This method will query the database to discover the parameters for the 
    /// stored procedure (the first time each stored procedure is called), and assign the values based on parameter order.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method provides no access to output parameters or the stored procedure's return value parameter.
    /// 
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  int orderCount = (int)ExecuteScalar(trans, "GetOrderCount", 24, 36);
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="transaction">A valid SqlTransaction</param>
    /// <param name="spName">The name of the stored procedure</param>
    /// <param name="parameterValues">An array of objects to be assigned as the input values of the stored procedure</param>
    /// <returns>An object containing the value in the 1x1 resultset generated by the command</returns>
    public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlTransaction transaction, string spName, params object[] parameterValues)
    {
        if( transaction == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "transaction" );
        if( transaction != null && transaction.Connection == null ) throw new ArgumentException( "The transaction was rollbacked or commited, please provide an open transaction.", "transaction" );
        if( spName == null || spName.Length == 0 ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "spName" );

        // If we receive parameter values, we need to figure out where they go
        if ((parameterValues != null) && (parameterValues.Length > 0)) 
        {
            // PPull the parameters for this stored procedure from the parameter cache (or discover them & populate the cache)
            SqlParameter[] commandParameters = SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(transaction.Connection, spName);

            // Assign the provided values to these parameters based on parameter order
            AssignParameterValues(commandParameters, parameterValues);

            // Call the overload that takes an array of SqlParameters
            return ExecuteScalar(transaction, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, commandParameters);
        }
        else 
        {
            // Otherwise we can just call the SP without params
            return ExecuteScalar(transaction, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName);
        }
    }


/// <summary>
    /// Execute a SqlCommand (that returns a 1x1 resultset) against the database specified in the connection string 
    /// using the provided parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  int orderCount = (int)ExecuteScalar(connString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetOrderCount", new SqlParameter("@prodid", 24));
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="connectionString">A valid connection string for a SqlConnection</param>
    /// <param name="commandType">The CommandType (stored procedure, text, etc.)</param>
    /// <param name="commandText">The stored procedure name or T-SQL command</param>
    /// <param name="commandParameters">An array of SqlParamters used to execute the command</param>
    /// <returns>An object containing the value in the 1x1 resultset generated by the command</returns>
    public static object ExecuteScalar(string connectionString, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        if( connectionString == null || connectionString.Length == 0 ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "connectionString" );
        // Create & open a SqlConnection, and dispose of it after we are done
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Call the overload that takes a connection in place of the connection string
            return ExecuteScalar(connection, commandType, commandText, commandParameters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some times you can connect and some times you can't?

Comment: Indeed.  And it isn't always the same database on the server.  Other databases are being accessed on the server at the same time, but "randomly" I will get login failed for various databases.  This is a very active application (40 million requests per day).  This same database that threw the login error has worked earlier in the day and even after the error without any human intervention.

Comment: how about showing how you are connecting perhaps it's an issue with your connection string.. and or another process can't tell without seeing any code..are you absolutely certain that you have that System Account setup properly is it using a static password or is it connected to the `Domain` perhaps the Login is locked becasue of too many bad attempts which would make me wonder if the password expired or is not set to `never expires`

Comment: MethodMan might be on to something.  If you have an application, maybe an old one, somewhere with a connection string that has the wrong password, then it could be repeatedly trying to connect and triggering a lockout.  I'm not sure where failed logins are logged, probably event viewer, where there might be more information.

Comment: @MethodMan, I have updated my question to include how the connection string is generated.  The domain account is not locked out.  The password never expires.  The account was able to connect to the database before and after the error without human intervention.

Comment: I see the code.. but curious.. when are you actually opening the connection..? also have you stepped thru the code you posted and are all expected values being populated / returned..? also ` public static string GetConnString(string DBName)` can you show what `DBName` looks like what if the servers that you are trying to connect to don't have that `Database` name that you are passing.. are you assuming that all environments in your server farm are setup the same in that regard..?

Comment: @AaronLS, this is a domain account using a trusted connection.  The account is not locked out and the password not expired.  The connection worked earlier in the day and has worked since the error.

Comment: how come you are not storing the connection string in a .config file.. you know that you can have numerous connection strings setup based on configuring them with the `{0}....{4}` construct for example.. in regards to assigning your `DataSource` if it's worked since then ..perhaps someone on the network or database side had password expired or never expires setup improperly.. otherwise I would expect you to be able to replicate the issue multiple times.. unless the password on the others machines was infact different in regards to `case sensitivity`

Comment: @MethodMan, this application actually connects to thousands of databases that we host.  We actually have a separate database with a table of database names and the servers that they are currently running on.  We lookup the details of a particular database then build a connection string from there.  The config file is impractical for our needs.  Bottom line, we will get random login failures on this and other databases even though the the domain account is a sysadmin, not locked out, not password expired.

Comment: only think I see after looking at your code is when and where are you opening the connection..? also I would take advantage of `wrapping` your code in the stringbuilder and anything related to your `DataBase Objects`, around a `using(){})`  I still don't see a `command.connection.Open()` anywhere in regards to your objects

Answer (score 0):

From the error log, I see you cannot open a database. Since you didn't share the code, that's pretty much the only thing we can currently take care of - so let's focus on that.

---

Inability to open a database might be a result of a few causes, the most popular ones being:

- You lack premissions
- The database is already locked by another source
- The database is not well specified.

### Permissions

Databases, in the end, are a file handled by the system. Thus, in order to edit them, you need the required credetinals - which could depend on many things. For example, a file which is held on a user on a windows NT system may be only accessable for this user and a few others; another good example is if you try to execute a command from the CMD which requires an administrator.

**Solution**:
Run as admin. See what happens. Solved your problem? require an admin access in the configuration file, and the problem is solved.

### Database locked

Database systems have many shananigans to them. Let's take for example Microsoft Access - It's a great system, but new users take a few trys before they understand how to fix their mistakes with it. The reason is simple - Access is very egoistic about it's objects. Their names, threads, constants, and methods have to occur in a very specific way, otherwise the system just throws an exception and a message box, which in visual studio will usually result in an  undetailed exception. In your case, the database system might be similar - It might be currently locked because of many reasons.

**Solution**: Close the DB application after saving it if it's open. Manually remove the processess related, and if none of the above worked, restart your computer.

### Database specification

This error is actually quite similar to the last one, but here the source is not the database application, but the operating system itself. This might be a result of wrong file names, DB types, etc. and the solution is to look deep into your code (feel free to share it, we could help you with that) and look for bad castings, connections, paths, and all that stuff.

**Solution**: As i mentioned, just take a deep look into the code. Rewrite the connection part if neccessary.

Edit: Regarding the error, i just noticed you get the SQL 4060. That's actually perfectly fit for your description - executting it from different workspaces might get you different premissions. Try the solutions i mentioned under the "Premissions" paragraph and let us know how it went.

Comment: There is a SQL Error of 4060 that I have been unable to find any clear definition on.  Also, as I have said, the exact code works on the same database just randomly it won't.

Comment: @Jeremy Rammalaere Just saw that part. SQL Error 4060 is relevant to the Premissions part. Try the solutions i mentioned there.

Comment: The application user does not handle the SQL server files (*.mdf & *.ldf) directly.  SQL Server controls all of the file IO to its database files.  My application user is setup on SQL Server as a sysadmin.  The account is not locked out and the password is not expired.  So I should not be getting failed logins.

Comment: Well then, I think the solution is to try breakpoints and tell us where exacly does the code crush, and add the details with it (are the cerdetinals well set in the breakpoint? Are there any time variables?) @JeremyRammalaere

Comment: The errors are random.  This database login failure may not happen again for weeks.  Another database on the same server may well have the error still today.  There will be millions of queries ran against this server today and a handful will have a login failure.  I was hoping that based on the fact that the same query when re-run works just fine there would be someone out there who has seen this type of behavior on SQL Server.

Comment: I see... I can't really help you then. I was thinking of much more simple problems. Good luck finding the solution! When you find it, let me know.

Comment: you mean *Permissions